# Get a DateTime object from an ISO 8601 duration

Tags: powershell, datetime, timespan, iso8601

In PowerShell, is there any way to translate a [duration as specified by ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) to a DateTime object? For example, **PT30M** is 30 minutes ago, so if the time now was `2019-07-31 17:00:00` I'd want a timestamp of `2019-07-31 16:30:00`.

I've tried the obvious -

```
"PT30M" | Get-Date
```

But that (unsurprisingly fails)

> Get-Date : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

My next thought is to write a function that will extract days, hours and minutes (for example, up to only 30 days max). To that end, the below function works and creates `$startTime` based on the `$Duration` passed in.

However, it feels a bit wrong. Firstly, the regex's only check very specifically for days, minutes and hours, and the rest of the `$Duration` could be utter rubbish. Secondly, it would be cumbersome once things like seconds, weeks and months are taken in to account.

Is there a built in way of doing this, or is persisting with the function below the best option?

```
function Get-TimespanFromDuration
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Duration
    )

    $now = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
    $dataTimeAgo = @{ "Days" = 0; "Hours" = 0; "Minutes" = 0 }

    ### Work out how may days ago.
    $daysAgo = $Duration -match "\D([1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)D"
    if ($daysAgo)
    {
        [int]$dataTimeAgo["Days"] = $matches[0] -replace "\D+"
    }

    ### Work out how may hours ago.
    $hoursAgo = $Duration -match "\D([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])H"
    if ($daysAgo)
    {
        [int]$dataTimeAgo["Hours"] = $matches[0] -replace "\D+"
    }

    ### Work out how many minutes ago.
    $minutesAgo = $Duration -match "\D([1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|60)M"
    if ($minutesAgo)
    {
        [int]$dataTimeAgo["minutes"] = $dataTimeAgo["minutes"] + ($matches[0] -replace "\D+")
    }

    $startTime = $now.AddDays(-($dataTimeAgo["Days"])).AddHours(-($dataTimeAgo["hours"])).AddMinutes(-($dataTimeAgo["minutes"])).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0Z")
    $endTime = $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.0Z")

    return ("{0}/{1}" -f $startTime, $endTime)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a .NET class you can use in PowerShell: `[System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("PT30M")`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this does not work for week duration. e.g. Converting "P20W" duration to timespan fails:
[system.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("P20W")
MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToTimeSpan" with "1" argument(s): "The string 'P20W' is not a valid TimeSpan value."

As per ISO_8601 definition standard, it is valid duration, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601